# javascript canvas - check if images created with toDataURL() are loaded

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, todataurl

I'm loading an image into my albImg array.

in my loop i then do this:

```
    for(var j = 1; j < albImg.length; j++){
        if(albImg[j].complete == true && albImg[j].width > 0){
            loadedimages++;
        }
    }
```

to make sure all my images are loaded.
I then call my flipImg() function like this:

```
    if(loadedimages == albImg.length-1){
         flipImg();
    }
```

I then flip an image and

```
ctx2.save();
ctx2.scale(-1, 1);
for (var i = RszSpriteCount; i < sprites.length; i++) {
    ctx2.drawImage(albImg[sprites[i][0]], sprites[i][1], sprites[i][2], sprites[i][3], sprites[i][4], 0 - (sprites[i][1] + sprites[i][3]), sprites[i][2], sprites[i][3], sprites[i][4]);
}
ctx2.restore();
var flipSz = albImg.length;
albImg[flipSz] = new Image();
albImg[flipSz].src = cnv2.toDataURL();
```

Here's where my problem begins.

The new image I created - albImg[5] - can't be displayed until it is loaded.
But it is created as if it already is loaded.

That is to say that:

albImg[5].width is already set (to 750) before I can display it.
albImg[5].complete is set to true, before I can display it.
albImg[5].onload = ctx.drawImage(albImg[5], 0, 0); will try to draw the image before it is loaded.

How can I check if my flipped image really is loaded before I display it? in Javascript?

(due to circumstances I'm not using jQuery for this)

Please help.

Comment: Why would `onload` try to display before image is loaded? Invocation of `onload` means that image is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main error is in how you do set the `onload` event handler :

```
albImg[5].onload = ctx.drawImage(albImg[5], 0, 0)
```

will set the return value of `drawImage()` (`undefined`) to the `onload` listener.

What you want is

```
albImg[5].onload = e => ctx.drawImage(albImg[5], 0, 0);
```

or

```
albImg[5].onload = function(){ ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0) };
```

---

For the `complete` and `width` properties set to true, it's because while the loading of an Image is **always** async, in your case, the image is probably already HTTP cached.
Since the HTTP loading and the javascript execution are not executed on the same thread, it is possible that the Image actually loaded before the browser returns its properties.

But even then, the onload event will fire (best to set it before the `src` though).

```js
var cacher = new Image();
cacher.onload = function(){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    console.log('"onload" fires asynchronously even when cached');
    };
  img.src = c.toDataURL();
  console.log('cached : ', img.complete, img.naturalWidth);
  }
cacher.src = c.toDataURL();
console.log('before cache :', cacher.complete, cacher.naturalWidth);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

So when dealing with an new Image (not one in the html markup), always simply listen to its `onload` event.

---

Now, with the few information you gave in your question, it would seem that you don't even need these images, nor to deal with any of their loadings (except for the sprites of course), since you can directly and synchronously call `ctx.drawImage(CanvasElement, x, y)`.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 75);
ctx.lineTo(0, 150);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(120,120,30, .35)';
ctx.fill();

const flipped = c.cloneNode(); // create an offscreen canvas
const f_ctx = flipped.getContext('2d');
f_ctx.setTransform(-1, 0,0,1, c.width, 0);// flip it
f_ctx.drawImage(c,0,0);// draw the original image

// now draw this flipped version on the original one just like an Image.
ctx.drawImage(flipped, 0,0);
// again in 3s
setTimeout(()=>ctx.drawImage(flipped, 150,0), 3000);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: I solved it thanks to you.

And for anyone seeing this in the future:
I added your code and it didn't work, but what I realized was that the image being drawn to the canvas was also generated by toDataUrl(). That picture wasn't always loaded on the canvas that I based my second image on.

Blank canvas = empty image.

Implementing your onload on the first image however solved the issue. Now a picture will always be loaded, ergo loaded image will always contain the flipped image.

Comment: And the reason I am loading it in an image first is because I figure that by flipping the image just once instead of several times on every loop I would be saving some processing power and hopefully lead to less battery usage (it's for a mobile app).

Does that make sense? Maybe I've just been overthinking it.

Comment: @DanielBengtsson, it makes sense, but it's not the best way no. If it's really just flipping an image (or a canvas which acts as it), then it will consume less memory to simply change the transform matrix of your visible canvas and use drawImage. If it were an full composition, then it would be better to use an offscreen canvas (like I did in the answer), and keep an reference to this offscreen canvas. Converting to Image is always heavy for memory. The browser will have to keep the b64 string representation of the file + the decoded image.